# How to run "gmake install"?

Tags: macos, matlab, gnu-make

I am now installing a code on my mac.

The code is from [here](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/segbench/). Look for "Benchmark and Boundary Detection Code" in this page.

In the readme file, it says:

> (1) For the image and segmentation reading routines in the Dataset
>   directory to work, make sure you edit Dataset/bsdsRoot.m to point to
>   your local copy of the BSDS dataset.
>
> (2) Run 'gmake install' from this directory to build everything.  You
>   should then probably put the lib/matlab directory in your MATLAB path.
>
> (3) Read the Benchmark/README file.

For the 1st step, I did as suggested.
For the 2nd step, I am pretty confused. I ran command `gmake install` in MATLAB, however, I got:

```
gmake

Undefined function or variable 'gmake'.
```

Actually, before running MATLAB, I installed gmake port through macports.

I just did it in terminal, however, this is what I got...

```
hou229:segbench yaozhongsong$ cd /Users/yaozhongsong/Documents/MATLAB/segbench
hou229:segbench yaozhongsong$ sudo gmake install
gmake[1]: execvp: ../Util/gethosttype: Permission denied
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/Users/yaozhongsong/Documents/MATLAB/segbench/Util'
GNUmakefile-library:26: *** mexSuffix not defined.  Stop.
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/Users/yaozhongsong/Documents/MATLAB/segbench/Util'
hou229:segbench yaozhongsong$
```

In MATLAB, I also did like this:

```
!gmake install
/bin/bash: gmake: command not found
```

How to do the 2nd step in readme file?

Thanks in advance!

@Amro

```
hou229:segbench yaozhongsong$ cd /Users/yaozhongsong/Documents/MATLAB/segbench
hou229:segbench yaozhongsong$ sudo gmake install
Password:
gmake[1]: execvp: ../Util/gethosttype: Permission denied
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/Users/yaozhongsong/Documents/MATLAB/segbench/Util'
mkdir -p ../lib/matlab
g++ -g -Wall -fPIC -I../include -O3 -DNOBLAS -c Exception.cc -o build//Exception.o
g++ -g -Wall -fPIC -I../include -O3 -DNOBLAS -c String.cc -o build//String.o
g++ -g -Wall -fPIC -I../include -O3 -DNOBLAS -c Random.cc -o build//Random.o
g++ -g -Wall -fPIC -I../include -O3 -DNOBLAS -c Timer.cc -o build//Timer.o
g++ -g -Wall -fPIC -I../include -O3 -DNOBLAS -c Matrix.cc -o build//Matrix.o
Matrix.cc:13:21: error: ieee754.h: No such file or directory
Matrix.cc: In function ‘double nextpow2(double)’:
Matrix.cc:86: error: ‘ieee754_double’ was not declared in this scope
Matrix.cc:86: error: expected `;' before ‘val’
Matrix.cc:87: error: ‘val’ was not declared in this scope
Matrix.cc:88: error: ‘IEEE754_DOUBLE_BIAS’ was not declared in this scope
Matrix.cc: At global scope:
Matrix.cc:48: warning: ‘snan’ defined but not used
Matrix.cc:49: warning: ‘inf’ defined but not used
gmake[1]: *** [build//Matrix.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/Users/yaozhongsong/Documents/MATLAB/segbench/Util'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the "mexSuffix not defined" error, first run `mexext` inside MATLAB, take that output (I suspect it is `mexmaci64`), edit the file `Util/GNUmakefile-library` and add the following at line 24:

```
mexSuffix := mexmaci64
```

replace the value with the one you get from `mexext`

Note: I haven't tested any of this, I am on a Windows machine..

Comment: Should be possible to pass the variable also on the command line without tinkering with the file, though. Still +1.

Comment: @YaozhongSong: ok the webpage says "the code is known to build and work on Intel/Linux platforms", and link to these [notes](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/segbench/macnotes.txt) for Mac... I'm guessing you are missing a dependency?

Comment: @YaozhongSong: one more try; edit the file `include/Matrix.hh` and set the line 19 to `#define NEXTPOW2 0`

Comment: @Amro According to the notes, I should edit two files. Are they ../Util/gethosttype and  ../Util/GNUmakefile? As there are two GNUmakefile...

Comment: @YaozhongSong: better yet just add `#undef NEXTPOW2` to `include/Matrix.cc` at line 11. As to which makefile, they meant the one in Utils

Comment: @Amro For the notes, matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -r "mex $(mexFlags) $< $(buildObjs) $(mexLibs) $(mexLibs); exit"
/Applications/MATLAB74/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -r "mex $(mexFlags) $< $(buildObjs) $(mexLibs) $(mexLibs); exit"   Should i replace all lines in GUNmakefile by these?

Comment: @Amro add #undef NEXTPOW2 at line 11? line 11 is comment?

Comment: @YaozhongSong: no, you find the four occurrences of that first line, and you replace each with the second line

Comment: @YaozhongSong: oops I meant line 11 of the file `Utils/Matrix.cc`

Comment: @Amro the four occurrences of the 1st line?

Comment: @YaozhongSong: find the following line in `Utils/GNUmakefile`: `matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -r "mex $(mexFlags) $< $(buildObjs) $(mexLibs) $(mexLibs); exit"` and replace the four occurrences by `/Applications/MATLAB74/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -r "mex $(mexFlags) $< $(buildObjs) $(mexLibs) $(mexLibs); exit"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run gmake from the Terminal (command line), not in MATLAB.

Comment: or type `!gmake install` inside MATLAB

Comment: I did it in terminal just now. It returns some error as I added in my question.

Comment: What does ls -l ../Util/gethosttype show? You might need to chmod +x ../Util/gethosttype (Edit: looks like you removed your comment with the output from gmake install?)

Comment: >> ls -l /Users/yaozhongsong/Documents/MATLAB/segbench/Util/gethosttype
                   -rw-r--r--  1 yaozhongsong  staff  841 Apr  9  2007 /Users/yaozhongsong/Documents/MATLAB/segbench/Util/gethosttype

Comment: Try chmod +x ../Util/gethosttype . That script is not executable, so gmake is returning a "Permission denied" error.

Comment: @YaozhongSong: maybe `gmake` is not on the `PATH`? doesn't matter just use the shell :)