# Using Gmake install on 64-bit Mac?

Tags: macos, matlab, 64-bit, benchmarking, image-segmentation

I am following a protocol from EECS UC Berkeley, and the step that I need help with is:

> (3) Download and untar the boundary detection benchmark code. Edit the matlab function Dataset/bsdsRoot.m so that it points to the BSDS300 directory created in the previous step.  Now run 'gmake install' from the root code directory.

I have been following the steps from this guideline, and I've linked the source that I've been using. I have XCode and Mac, but I am having problems with the gmake install. I did the changes as suggested by https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/segbench/macnotes.txt , but I am still getting plenty of errors. If I do `mexSuffix := mexmaci 64` with the ifeq check for the type of machine/system (as stipulated in the changes for Mac), I get a Permission Denied. If I do not use the ifeq check, then this is what I get:

```
Siddharths-MacBook-Pro-2:segbench Eruption$ sudo gmake install
make[1]: execvp: ../Util/gethosttype: Permission denied
g++ -g -Wall -fPIC -I../include -O3 -DNOBLAS -c Matrix.cc -o build//Matrix.o
In file included from Matrix.cc:8:
./Matrix.hh:151:19: error: friend declaration specifying a default argument must
      be a definition
    friend Matrix rot90 (const Matrix& a, int k = 1);
                  ^
./Matrix.hh:183:19: error: friend declaration specifying a default argument must be a definition friend Matrix diag (const Matrix& a, int k = 0);
Matrix.cc:13:10: fatal error: 'ieee754.h' file not found #include <ieee754.h>
```

I am not sure what I need to be doing. If someone has experience using the EECS Berkeley Benchmarks on a 64-bit Mac, that would be really helpful. Thank you so much! Here's the link to the question that I had been following as well. [How to run "gmake install"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299958/how-to-run-gmake-install)